# Modifying standard DTT scripts to use -c instead of $1

Tags: kernel, solaris, dtrace, tracing

There are lots of great dtrace programs out there and some of them require a PID to be passed to them, in order for them to trace that PID. Inside the dtrace scripts that argument is stored in $1. Is it possible to just simply replace $1 with $target and -c on the cmdline, and rest of the script logic remains the same?

Is it just as simple as I think it should be?

Answer (score 0):

You would have to populate the variable `$target` within your script like for example `target=$1`. Simply replacing it will not suffice and not work.

Lets see what we can find on documentation about this:

> [*Positional parameters*](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/othertypesv.html)
>
> Arguments passed to the script from the command line [[1]](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/othertypesv.html#FTN.AEN2450) : `$0, $1, $2, $3 ...`
>
> `$0` is the name of the script itself, `$1` is the first argument, `$2` the second, `$3` the third, and so forth. [[2]](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/othertypesv.html#FTN.AEN2464) After `$9`, the arguments
>   must be enclosed in brackets, for example, `${10}, ${11}, ${12}`.
>
> The special variables [`$*` and `$@`](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/internalvariables.html#APPREF) denote all the positional parameters.

What you can do however is something similar to this to make it more readable inside the script:

```bsh
#!/bin/sh
target=$1
```

But that would mean nesting variables/data which is by most people coding seen as a bad practice.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! However, my question was very specific to the D language I.e dtrace' language... I think it works differently to bash.

Comment: No, it doesn't yet answer my question :)

Comment: Then you maybe should [include such a script into your question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/406175/edit), so people actually see what you're talking about.